# Razor MVC - Object Edit Field Change Log

Tags: asp.net, razor

Users modify a DB object in an edit form that I have, pretty straight forward.

I need to implement a 'change log' on this object. I need to record which fields where changed and what they were before and after. I'm using Razor MVC.

Comment: I've looked all around for a strategy to do it, that's why that is what I'm asking.
I've looked into pulling the record from the DB and comparing(which may be a possible solution, but there are issues that I would have to work around related to objects that aren't in the db, but are joined)
I'm looking for the best way to attack this.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by writing triggers for the table on update/delete.  On update/delete of a record, the trigger pushes the record to a History table, in a History database.  This creates the change log.  Then you would just need to display it; to identify the change would require evaluating each and every field.

There's nothing already built that wold do this for you that I know of.

Comment: This is a possible solution. I am interacting with various DB's(MySQL, MSSql, Oracle SQL), so this is a route I would prefer to stay away from.
The other issue would be how to pass the name through to the DB, you could pass it in as a column('LastUpdatedUser'), but I was hoping there would be a decent way to do this in C#, so the logic is all in the same place.

Comment: The only way to track changes is to have a history of those changes, so you have to utilize a DB in some way.  How else would you know what changes, if you don't have anything to compare.  It could even be as simple as a table that stores the descriptions of changes made to a table's data between version 1 and version 2...

Comment: Absolutely, that would be the plan. I would prefer there to be a way to do this in the post request handler, not in a DB trigger because of the different databases we use from the different systems we have integrated.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying.  Essentially you'd have to pull the current record, then do a manual, or more preferrably, a reflection-based compare, grab the differences, and then commit them.  Doable, not an easy effort, but doable.

Comment: yup - that would probably be the way to go. I was just hoping there was something that did more of the heavy lifting for me.